# how to use all the results from an explode an split array in a statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, replace

I am trying to use all the `value` from a variable `keywords` (#top #travel #italy) to split using `explode()` to search in the db and then to show the results. I made a part but it is showing me only the results which match with the last word from the query, so in my case only `#italy` and I want to show all the words`#top #travel #italy`

```
    $keywordArray = explode(' ',  $keyword);
foreach($keywordArray as $keywordArrayGo){
$sqlKeywordArray = "SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews FROM stiinta WHERE   approved='1' AND  replace(replace(replace(keywords, ',', ''), '-', ' '), ' ', '') LIKE  concat('%', ? , '%')  UNION SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews FROM travel WHERE   approved='1' AND  replace(replace(replace(keywords, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  concat('%', ? , '%')  UNION SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews FROM natura WHERE   approved='1' AND  replace(replace(replace(keywords, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  concat('%', ? , '%')  UNION SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews FROM travel WHERE   approved='1' AND  replace(replace(replace(keywords, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  concat('%', ? , '%')  UNION SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews FROM lifestyle WHERE   approved='1' AND  replace(replace(replace(keywords, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  concat('%', ? , '%')  LIMIT 10";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sqlKeywordArray);
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $keywordArrayGo, $keywordArrayGo, $keywordArrayGo, $keywordArrayGo, $keywordArrayGo); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
 /* Get the number of rows */
  $checkQuery = $stmt->num_rows;
echo  "$keywordArrayGo : $checkQuery : QUERY care sa se potriveasca <br>";
if ($checkQuery == 0) {// verificare daca este vrun query
    echo "<FONT color='red'><strong>NU SE POTRIVESTE NICIO INREGISTRARE.</strong><br></font>";
}
$stmt->bind_result($idSearch, $titluKEY, $linkKEY, $pozaKEY, $altKEY, $keywordKEY, $linknewsKEY);//variabla pe care o vrei inlocuita prin bind_Result in loc de get_Result
$keywordArticleMatch ="";
while ($stmt->fetch())    {
       // faci acelasi lucru fara $row trb sa fie in concordanta cu ceea ce este in SELECT column pentretu teste a href="/page-stiinta.php?pid='.$linkKEY.'"
    $keywordArticleMatch .= '<div id="articol-content-more"><a href="/'.$linknewsKEY.'"><img src="/images/'.$pozaKEY.'.jpg"class="articol-content-more-image" alt="'.$altKEY.'"><p class="articol-content-more-title">'.$titluKEY.'</p></a><span><a class="articol-content-more-afla" href="/'.$linknewsKEY.'">Citește mai multe</a></span><span class="articol-content-more-fl"><div class="fb-share-button" data-layout="button_count" data-href="http://esticurios.ro/'.$linknewsKEY.'"></div></span></div><br>';        
    }
  /* free results */
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
}//close first loop
```

I missed something and I do not know what I missed.

Comment: Have you ruled out using `FULLTEXT` search? It may deliver the functions you need.

Comment: no I dont know, can you show me a exemple? please

Comment: Use your favorite search engine to look for `mysql fulltext search ~example`. There's plenty of good material out there.

Comment: I searched but i didnot understand, can you some me on this cause...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `execute` on a series of SELECT statements in a loop, then using `bind` to capture the resultset on the last one after you exit the loop.

If you're going to gather results from a series of SELECT statements this way, you have to retrieve and store the resultset that comes from each distinct `execute` call. You can't wait until after the loop is done.

Comment: oK, but how I can do that?